# JavaScript: How to write a function that accepts two arguments(numbers) that produces a grid?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Write a function makeGrid that accepts two arguments:

numColumns (number) - how many columns we want our grid to have

numRows (number) - how many rows we want our grid to have

makeGrid should return a two-dimensional array that represents a grid of the given dimensions.

What i did:

```
function makeGrid(numColumns, numRows){
    const arrayX = []
    const arrayY = []
    for (let i=1; i<=numColumns; i++){
        arrayX.push(numColumns[i])
    }
    for(let j=1; j<=numRows; j++){
        arrayY.push(arrayX)
    }
    return arrayY
}
result = makeGrid(2,3)
console.log(result)
```

I was expecting: [[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]

What I got: [[undefined],[undefined],[undefined]]

Comment: `numColumns` is a number. What do you expect `numColumns[i]` to be?

Comment: I’m trying to create a counter that goes from 1-numColumns. E.g. numColumns(5) = 1,2,3,4,5. And then placing these numbers into array X = [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: Yes but the using the [property accessor syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) on a variable that holds a number. Numbers don't have a property `i` (another number depending on the iteration of your loop). If you want to add the current iteration, then why not just use `i` instead of `numColumns[i]`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use Nested Loops :

```js
function makeGrid(numColumns, numRows){
    const result = [];
    for (let i=1; i<=numRows; i++){
      result[i-1] = [];
      for(let j=1; j<=numColumns; j++){
        result[i-1][j-1] = j;
      }    
    }
    
    return result;
}
result = makeGrid(2,3)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `new Array(x)` and `Array.fill` to accomplish this in a much simpler manner.

```js
function makeGrid(numColumns, numRows){
    const arrayX = new Array(numColumns).fill(0);
    const arrayY = new Array(numRows);
    for (let i=0; i<arrayY.length; i++){
        arrayY[i] = [...arrayX]; //We use this syntax to make copies of the array
    }
    return arrayY;
}
result = makeGrid(2,3);
console.log(result);
```

If you also want the arrays to contain column numbers, you can just insert another loop:

```js
function makeGrid(numColumns, numRows){
    const arrayX = new Array(numColumns);
    const arrayY = new Array(numRows);
    for (let x=0; x<arrayX.length; x++) {
        arrayX[x] = x + 1;
    }
    for (let i=0; i<arrayY.length; i++){
        arrayY[i] = [...arrayX];
    }
    return arrayY;
}
result = makeGrid(2,3);
console.log(result);
```

Edit: changed the syntax to make it a bit more readable.

Comment: `arrayX.map(x => x)`    or  `[...arrayX]`

Answer (score -1):

Just replace **arrayX.push(numColumns[i])** by **arrayX.push(i)**

```js
function makeGrid(numColumns, numRows){
    const arrayX = []
    const arrayY = []
    for (let i=1; i<=numColumns; i++){
        arrayX.push(i)
    }
    for(let j=1; j<=numRows; j++){
        arrayY.push(arrayX)
    }
    return arrayY
}
result = makeGrid(2,3)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: You can use `new Array(x)` and `Array.fill` to make this solution much simpler.

Comment: Try doing `result[0][0] = 7;` before your `console.log` to see something funky.. :)   To stop the funky stuff you could do -> `arrayY.push([...arrayX])`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).